# I can not make my collision work

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am new at javascript and I cannot work out where I am going wrong with the code. I think I know where the code is broken but I am not sure.

I think this is where the issue is:

```
if (testCollisionTile(tileList[key],bulletList[key]))
```

where it says `bulletList[key]`

When I run the page it says "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"

```js
var canv = document.getElementById("ctx");
var ctx =  canv.getContext('2d');
canv.setAttribute("height", "500px");
canv.setAttribute("width", "500px");
ctx.font = "20px verdana";
canv.style.border = "2px solid #000000";
// var space = new Image();
// space.src = "images/space.jpg";
canv.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/space.jpg')";
var numOfTiles, tileList, score, bulletList, timer, isPaused;
var WIDTH = 500;
var HEIGHT = 500;

 var tile = {
    height:10,
    width:30,
    color: 'red'
 };

 var base = {
    x:150,
    y:400,
    height: 20,
    width: 30,
    color: 'orange',
    pressingLeft:false,
    pressingRight:false,
    //lives:3,
 };

 var bullet = {
    height: 20,
    width: 2,
    color: 'white',
    spdX: -5,
    spdY: -5
 };

 document.onkeydown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode ==37) {
        base.pressingLeft = true;
        base.pressingRight =false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode ==39) {
        base.pressingLeft = false;
        base.pressingRight =true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode ==88) {

        if (isPaused) {
            isPaused = false;
        }

        else  {
        isPaused = true;
        }
 }
 };

 document.onkeyup = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode ==37) {
        base.pressingLeft = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode ==39) {

        base.pressingRight =false;
    }
 };


 drawTile = (t,i) => {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = tile.color;
    ctx.fillRect(t.x,t.y,tile.width,tile.height);
    ctx.restore();
};

drawBase = () => {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = base.color;
    ctx.fillRect(base.x,base.y,base.width,base.height);
    ctx.restore();

};

drawBullet = (b, i) => {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = bullet.color;
    ctx.fillRect(b.x,b.y,bullet.width,bullet.height);
    ctx.restore();

};


updateBasePosition = () => {
if (base.pressingLeft) {
    base.x = base.x - 5;
}
else if (base.pressingRight) {
    base.x = base.x + 5;
}
if (base.x < 0) {
    base.x = 0;
}
if (base.x > WIDTH-base.width) {
    base.x = WIDTH-base.width;
}
};

updateBullets = () => {
    for (key in bulletList) {
        bulletList[key].y -=10;
    } 
}

testCollisionTile = function(tile, bullet) {

    return ( (tile.x <= bullet.x + bullet.width) &&
             (bullet.x <= tile.x + tile.width) &&
             (tile.y <= bullet.y + bullet.height) &&
             (bullet.y <= tikeye.y + tile.height) );
     console.log('hello');
}
update = () => {
    if (!isPaused) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    drawBase();
    if (timer % 200 == 0) {     
        var bX = base.x+15;
        var bY = base.y;
        bulletList.push({x:bX,y:bY});
    };

    tileList.forEach(drawTile);

    bulletList.forEach(drawBullet);
    //console.log('hello');

     for (key in tileList) {
        if (testCollisionTile(tileList[key],bulletList[key])) {

        //  console.log('hello');
            delete tileList[key];

        // console.log('hello');

        }
    }

    updateBasePosition();   
    updateBullets();
    timer += 10;
}else {
    ctx.fillText('Game Over', 200,250);
}
};
startGame = () => {
numOfTiles = 0;
var tileX = 5;
var tileY = 150;
tileList=[];
bulletList=[];
tileX = 10;
    for(var j=1;j<=9;j++){
        tileList[numOfTiles] = {x:tileX,y:tileY};
        numOfTiles++;
        tileX += 55;
    }
timer = 0;
isPaused = false;
intervalVar = setInterval(update, 40);

};

startGame();
```

```html
 <canvas id="ctx" />
```

Comment: I can't tell at first glance: is there exactly one bullet per tile, and can only that bullet hit that tile? If not, e.g. any bullet can hit any tile, you don't want to be using the same `key` for both `tileList[key]` and `bulletList[key]` in your loop.

Comment: What line is your error happening on?

Comment: this line if (testCollisionTile(tileList[key],bulletList[key]))
in think it is this bit: bulletList[key]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
 for (key in tileList) {
    if (testCollisionTile( tileList[key], bulletList[key] )) {
```

You are assuming that the arrays `tileList` and `bulletList` have the same amount of keys, but they do not, you have to validate for that in the `testCollisionTile` or make sure they do have the same amount of items before you start the for loop

---

On a second thought I think you should be comparing every tile with every bullet:

```
for (tkey in tileList) {
    for (bkey in bulletList) {
        if (testCollisionTile( tileList[tkey], bulletList[bkey] )) {
            delete tileList[tkey];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is a spin on your code I'm using most of your code but I did change many key points
http://heldersepu.github.io/hs-scripts/HTML/canvasCollisions.html

Comment: I got pass your error `"Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"` but there are other issues in the logic of the OP the list of bullets is growing, we should have a process to clean them once the y goes into the negatives